# Included Javascript through ajax doesn't show in source

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Not really a problem, but more of a general question.

Say I have a php script being called by ajax....
within that php script is a bit more javascript that gets loaded into the dom on success...

Said javascript runs, everything works, but the source code doesn't show that javascript.
I know with firefox, to show dom-inserted stuff you need to select then "View Selection Source" which will show the dynamic stuff....

Why is it that dynamically loaded javascript from an ajax call doesn't show in the source code?

Comment: Not meaning to be flip, but because it's *not* in the source code? You loaded it dynamically.

Comment: no no, I mean.. all the dynamic stuff that gets added to the dom is put in the source code... why not the extra <script> stuff. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser's "View Page Source" feature will only display the source code of the main page as-is, i.e. the source code that was originally downloaded. Any subsequent dynamic additions or manipulations will only be performed in memory (e.g. through dynamic addition of the "<script>" tag or eval("some fetched javascript string")), and will not be reflected in the "View Page Source".

This is not a "legacy" situation as some may think, as web developers when troubleshooting will want to see the "static" page source to verify if the original page was rendered correctly in the first place.

To view the dynamic end-result, one could use [Firebug plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) (on Firefox) or Chrome's web developer tools (press F12)